# poor quality type on Chrome in Windows in 3440 x 1440

Tags: css, svg, fonts

Attached is an screenshop of type rendered as svg text in Chrome on Windows 10 for a desktop application I am writing.

[image]

The type is unacceptably pixelated. Here are the specs:

font: opentype

rendered as: svg text

css tried (in various combinations, to no effect): text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

monitor resolution: 3440 x 1440

Is there a way to improve the anti-aliasing of this text?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I later noticed that all text in the browser was rendering poorly, including regular HTML text. I happened to need to reinstall Windows 10 for another reason and upon doing that, this issue disappeared.